# Sistema de amigos em PHP e SQL

Tags: php, sql

tenho um problema e ainda não achei a solução. Tenho 2 tabelas, uma de utilizadores e outra de amigos.

Na tabela do utilizador eu guardo o `id` e o `username`

Na tabela de amigos tenho o campo `user_1_id` e o `user_2_id` , que contém apenas o id de utilizador dos dois amigos.

Como faço a consulta para a saída de amigos do utilizador logado com ID=6, incluindo os respetivos `username` dos amigos dele?

Comment: `SELECT * amigos user_1_id = $_SESSION['id']` onde a variável de sessão id guarda o id do user logado.. Daí ao pegar os dados tu faz outra consulta na tabela de usuários pelando o `username` do id que obteve na primeira consulta, ou pode fazer usando JOIN(eu acho).. Tente colocar o código que esta usando, assim aumenta a chance de resposta adequada.

Comment: mysql, postgresql, sqlserver?

Comment: Todas as perguntas dele foi usando o MySQL, acredito que se fosse outra iria avisar, mas boa questão. Falhei em deduzir que seria MySQL. Tenho que aprender a não responder perguntas vazias, mas não consigo. =(

Comment: @Inkeliz mas só de você ter entendido o meu ponto de vista tão facilmente com um comentário tão vago quanto o meu demonstra que você é inteligente e pega as coisas fácilmente, te dar uma dica, use sempre o botão pra [fechar] perguntas vagas, mesmo que seja coisa "boba". Fechar não é deletar ou banir é apenas prevenir que perguntas que necessitam de esclarecimentos recebam respostas sem atingir o padrão minimo de qualidade ;)

Comment: Não tenho acesso à esta função, acredito eu. Se tiver eu não sei onde é. Depois dou uma fuçada no Meta para ver se tem alguma coisa sobre isso. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras, com diferentes níveis de performance e facilidade.

```
SELECT utilizador.* FROM utilizador WHERE id IN (SELECT user_2_id FROM amigos WHERE user_1_id = '6');
```

Neste caso o user_2_id teria que ser sempre o amigo. Enquanto o user_1_id seria que ser sempre igual ao usuário conectado. Neste caso sempre que adicionasse alguém seria necessário haver dois `INSERT`.

*Existe duplicidade entre amigos (`user_1_id = 1` e `user_2_id = 2` | `user_1_id = 2` e `user_2_id = 1`) uma vez que cada um é amigo de cada um?* Se sim, está pronto!

Caso **não haja duplicidade** terá que fazer algumas mudanças, pode ver abaixo, ***mas não recomendo por grandes problemas de performance***, foi apenas para dar uma ideia e rapidamente.

```
SELECT utilizador.*  FROM utilizador WHERE (id IN (SELECT user_2_id FROM amigos WHERE user_1_id = '6') OR id IN (SELECT user_1_id FROM amigos WHERE user_2_id = '6')) AND id != '6';
```

O motivo disto é que EU posso adicionar ou seu aceito (por exemplo!) o que poderia fazer com que eu fosse um `user_1_id` ou `user_2_id`.

Para obter o '6' poderia usar `$_SESSION['']` ou `$_COOKIE['']` ou qualquer outro método similar, mas a questão parece ser a estrutura do MySQL e não isto.

Comment: Vou testar mais logo e já dou noticias. Mas parece ser isso mesmo. Vou ter que fazer mais um `INSERT` quando o utilizador aceita o amigo. Obrigado

Comment: obrigado isso resolveu o meu problema. Fiz mais um insert para o utilizador id=6 poder ser user_1_id e user_2_id. Depois eu chamo os amigos pela $_SESSION['id']. Obrigado!